# Building a Windows Service in VS.NET 2008

Tags: c#, windows-services, desktop-application

I am new Windows service in VS.Net 2008.

I need to build a Windows service Application.  When I right click the solution in Solution Explorer, a UI opens named Solution 'MySyncService'.  Here I can see two major folders Common Properties and Configuration Properties. But I cannot see a general tab.

Secondly, if I right click my project 'MySyncService',select properties(short cut menu), then I can't see Common Properties and Configuration Properties. I see various tabs like Application Build, Build Events, Debug, Resources, Services, Settings, Reference paths etc. As per the link in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) I am not able to get the Common properties and General Tab. Please let me know which step I am missing.

Comment: what exactly are you trying right now? This almost read like you don't understand how to handle the IDE not like you got a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.Make sure you select VS 2008 from the quasi-dropdown up top

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Application > Startup object under the project settings for the selected service project.